# How do I call my role-based authorized web API from another app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web API that utilizes role authorization ( ex: `[Authorize(Roles="test")]` ) for each controller and action.

This API is meant to be a stand alone app with no actual MVC site for it, so there is no login method.

So let's say I have a separate "**Students**" app that needs to display a list of all current students in the school. In the API, I have a role-based authorized method that retrieves all current students from the database. How would I be able to call that API call from the "**Students**" app (which is on the same domain) if it's authorized?

Is there anyway I can spoof the "**Students**" app to run under one of the authorized roles? I don't want to use the roles of the user using the site because only Admins are allowed to execute these API calls.

Comment: how are you authenticating?

Comment: @Alex OAuth 2 (specifically with Google)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this tutorial on building an [OAuth 2 authorization server](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server). You can use the Authorization Code Grant to authenticate your Students MVC app against your API.

Building an OAuth server is not a simple task, however. You can look at a complete and secure open source product like [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) to help you implement most of the authorization and authentication logic.